# Convert specific format from string to LocalDateTime

Tags: java

I have this method:

```
   private static LocalDateTime setActivationDate(final String date) {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyy");
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date, dateFormatter);
        return LocalDateTime.of(ld, LocalDateTime.MIN.toLocalTime());
    }
```

When i pass value `dd.MM.yyyy` for example: `14.01.2022` i get this:

```
2022-01-14T00:00
```

But I want to return and seconds also..so that format looks like this:

```
2022-01-14T00:00:00
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Note that you'e only _parsing_ the string to `LocalDateTime` but you don't define any _format_ for a conversion back to a string (nor did you share how you're doing that). I assume the output you get results from calling `toString()` on the `LocalDateTime` you're returning.

Comment: im returning LocalDateTime, this method is all what im doing... and i just pass this String date "14.01.2022". I need something else to add?

Comment: Btw, the name `setActivationDate(...)` seems to be very misleading since it doesn't set anything, looks like a setter but is a static utility method. I'd rename it to something more sensible in order to avoid confusion if you or someone else needs to read that code in the future (think of yourself trying to remember wtf this method is doing 6 months from now).

Comment: ok, tnx..i will rename it :) but right now bigger problem is that i can not get seconds in this conversion :/

Comment: "I need something else to add?" - In that method you probably don't have to add anything. This method basically takes a date and creates a `LocalDateTime` using that date string and time 00:00:00. So you get a valid `LocalDateTime` _object_ that you can work with and that has even higher precision than just seconds. If you want to output that time you need another `DateTimeFormatter` to format the object back to a string. What you didn't show is how you're producing the output - I _guess_ you're doing just a `System.out.println(...)`, aren't you?

Comment: yes, only that and there i see that output result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LocalDateTime` omits the seconds when they are `00`.
If you want to get them use the `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` formatter:

```java
String date = "14.01.2022";
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyy");
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date, dateFormatter);

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(ld, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);

System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
```

Prints

```
2022-01-14T00:00:00
```

If you take a look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--), `toString` explains the behaviour:

> Outputs this date-time as a String, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.
> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS
>
> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are **implied to be zero**.